# django-cms page permission defaults when making a new django-cms page

Tags: django-cms

When making a new django-cms page, there is a check box named "Login required" and a select button named "Menu visibility" in the page permissions form. We're hoping that by default, when a new page is made, "login required" is already checked and the "Menu visibility" option "for logged in users only" is selected. Is this possible? I've been searching through stack overflow and the django-cms issues list in their repository for something similar to the situation i'm in but i couldn't find any.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you may need to hook into [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/) and detect new page creation to populate defaults.

For example, the [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#pre-save) signal on Page or Title (have a look which of the models have that field) can be used to first detect if id is present and if not, defaults can be populated.

Comment: hi petr. it worked. there's a created flag for post_save that could be checked which would indicate if a model is newly created. thanks